# Письмо не отображается картинка в html письме и письмо попадает в спам. почему так происходит?

Tags: email, вёрстка-email

Письмо не отображается картинка в html письме и письмо попадает в спам. почему так происходит?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"><meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/arial-2" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-55" rel="stylesheet">
                
                
    </head>
    <style>   
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Arial';
        src: url(/fonts/arialmt.ttf);
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Arial';
        src: url(/fonts/Arial_bold.ttf);
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Helvetica';
        src: url(/fonts/helvetica_regular.otf);
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family:'Helvetica';
        src: url(/fonts/helvetica_bold.otf);
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    </style><body><div class="es-wrapper-color">
   
                <table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td class="esd-email-paddings" valign="top"><table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tbody><tr><td class="esd-stripe" align="center"><table class="es-content-body" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"><tbody><tr>
                <td class="esd-structure es-p20t es-p20r es-p20l" align="left">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  
                  <tbody><tr>
                         
                      <td width="560" class="esd-container-frame" align="left">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
                              <tbody><tr>
                <td align="center" class="esd-block-image" style="font-size: 0">
                    <a target="_blank">
                        <img class="adapt-img" src="https://qmtznh.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_82c6ab7b3479d34cc8c3f0aacdf4f86cebd3aab42216b136593813111f9c3e71/images/bet_jpeg.jpg" alt="" width="560">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
                      </td>
                    
                          
                  </tr>
              
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td class="esd-structure es-p20t es-p20r es-p20l" align="left">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  
                  <tbody><tr>
                          
                      <td width="560" class="esd-container-frame" align="left" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
                              <tbody><tr>
                <td align="left" class="esd-block-text" >
                    <p style="margin-bottom:10px;color:#323232;  font-family: 'Montserrat','Helvetica','Arial'; sans-serif;font-size: 24px;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;text-align:center;">尊敬的客户</p>
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td class="esd-block-html es-p10b" style="display: block;margin-bottom: 10px;padding:20px 20px; border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);background: #FFF;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);">
      <p style="color: #323232;padding-bottom:10px; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Montserrat','Helvetica','Arial';font-weight: 500;margin: 0;">老虎平台低价添加了一些新号码</p> 
      <p style="margin: 0;  font-family: 'Montserrat','Helvetica','Arial';font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;" esd-text="true" class="esd-text">可以选择这些国家: <span style="color: #323232;text-decoration: none;font-weight:700;font-weight:bold;">印度、印度尼西亚、美国、马来西亚、老挝、南非、越南、巴基斯坦、孟加拉国</span>注册账户可达数千个。</p> 
      </td>
          </tr></tbody></table>
                      </td>
                  
                          
                  </tr><tr>
                          
                      <td width="560" class="esd-container-frame" align="left">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
                              <tbody><tr>
            <td  style="padding: 20px 20px;border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);background: #FFF;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);">
      <p style="color: #323232;padding-bottom:10px;  font-family: 'Montserrat','Helvetica','Arial';font-size: 14px;font-weight: 700;margin: 0;">如果您订阅了我们的频道，就可以参加促销活动和竞赛， 获得7-9折的优惠码</p> 
      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat','Helvetica','Arial';font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;color: #323232;">关于 Tiger SMS 团队。</p> 
      </td>
          </tr><tr>
                <td align="left" >
                    <p style="margin: 0px;padding-top: 29px;padding-bottom:26px; font-family: 'Montserrat','Helvetica','Arial';font-size: 14px;font-weight: 700;text-align:center;color: #323232;">我们的 Telegram 频道</p>
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="center" class="esd-block-button es-p30b" style="margin-top:50px">
                  <span class="es-button-border" style="border-radius:10px;border-width:0;background:#323232">
                        <a href="https://t.me/tiger_sms_china" class="es-button es-button-6489" target="_blank" style="color:#FFF; font-family: 'Inter','Helvetica','Arial';font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;line-height:normal;border-radius:10px;padding:16px 32px;background:#323232;border-alt:10px solid #323232;text-decoration: none;">订阅</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="center" class="esd-block-text es-p40b">
                 <a style="display: block;margin-top: 46px;font-family: 'Montserrat','Helvetica','Arial';font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;text-align:center;color: #CE0606;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;" href="https://tiger-sms.com/ru">我们的网站</a>
                </p></td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
                      </td>
                  
                          
                  </tr>

                </tbody></table>
                </td>
              </tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></body></html>
```

Comment: если письмо попадает в спам, то с вероятностью, близкой к единице, это и есть [спам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC).

Comment: И также судя по содержимому... @aleksandrbarakin

Comment: а вообще поговаривают, что для людей, отправляющих вместо plain-текста всякий разрисованный мусор, уготовано в аду особо жаркое местечко.